# sum of values of overlapping purchase orders

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have several POs with values and I need to calculate the sum but also display all rows and columns
here is the input table, so the output remains same + extra column for sum, 150(for 1,2) or 200(for 4,5)

[image]

I can simple use analytical function to display the sum with the whole rows

```
select PO, start, end , value , sum(value) over (partition by start, end ) as sum 
from table;
```

but PO's don't overlap each other on exact date like this everytime, suppose there is another PO

[image]

there will be 2 cases

1. sum of values for PO's 1,2,3 which is 250
2. sum of values for PO's 3,4,5 which is 300

In the output I need to display the whole row+sum and of course the PO 3 must be displayed twice in this particular situation.

any idea?
thanks

Comment: And how are the dates calculated?  Your example of overlaps is quite simple.  What happens in more complex situations?

Comment: what do you mean be how are dates calculated? there are such simple overlaps and as i wrote in many cases there are several PO's with same timeframe(same start and end) so the analytical function could do but there could be a case when one or more PO's overlap  in 1 day only

Comment: Which oracle version are you using ?

Comment: oracle 12 version

Comment: You did said that you want `but also display all rows`. But you didn't say how the record for `PO=3` as individual should display. and also i am confused with why you need `of course the PO 3 must be displayed twice in this particular situation` .

Comment: each record(row) as in the table + there will be additional column for sum.so for PO 1 and 2 there will be 250 because of the case 1, then PO 3 with 250 as well. then you have case 2 so PO 3 again but this time with 300. same goes for PO 4 and 5.

Comment: What is the logical expression that determines that PO3 ends up in result set 1 and result set 2?

Comment: because PO3 overlaps PO1 and 2 therefore will be in the set 1 but PO3 overlaps PO4 and 5 as well then must be in set 2 as well . PO1 and 2 dont overlap PO4 and 5 so there must be 2 sets

Comment: Your example is a single case only. Are there more cases of overlapping periods or gaps? What PO-groups would you expect for: a) PO2 lasts only to 2020-01-31 ob b) PO2 last from 2019-12-01 to 2020-01-31 or c) PO2 2919-12-01 to 2020-03-31?